# Find the critical points of summation function

Tags: calculus

This a loss function, I want to find the critical points of it, the goal is to express the critical points by $a$ and $b$.
$$f(a,b)=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^nw_i(a+bx_i-y_i)^2$$

The usual way of doing it is gradient descent but I want to try using gradient vector.

These are my steps
[image]

After finding the partial derivatives of it, I tried to set it to be $0$. However, I don't know what to do next since it is a summation function.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&(\sum w_i )a+(\sum w_ix_i)b=\sum w_iy_i\\
&&(\sum w_ix_i) a+(\sum w_ix_i^2)b=\sum w_ix_iy_i.
\end{eqnarray}
By Gram's Rule, you have
\begin{eqnarray}
D=\bigg|\begin{matrix}\sum w_i &\sum w_ix_i\\
\sum w_ix_i&\sum w_ix_i^2
\end{matrix}\bigg|=\sum w_i\sum w_ix_i^2-(\sum w_ix_i)^2\\
D_1=\bigg|\begin{matrix}\sum w_iy_i &\sum w_ix_i\\
\sum w_ix_iy_i&\sum w_ix_i^2
\end{matrix}\bigg|=\sum w_iy_i\sum w_ix_i^2-(\sum w_ix_i)(\sum w_ix_iy_i)\\
D_2=\bigg|\begin{matrix}\sum w_i &\sum w_iy_i\\
\sum w_ix_i&\sum w_ix_iy_i
\end{matrix}\bigg|=\sum w_i\sum w_ix_iy_i-(\sum w_ix_i)(\sum w_iy_i)
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ a=\frac{D_1}{D}, b=\frac{D_2}{D}. $$